# How to avoid Fragment recreation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 `Fragments` **F1** and **F2**. I open the first `Fragment` **F1** from the `Activity` using the following code:

```
MyFragment f1 = new MyFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("GameLevelType", "Learn");
dialog.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction gameTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
gameTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
gameTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, f1).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Then from `Fragment` **F1** I am opening another `Fragment` **F2** using below code:

```
MySecondFragment f2 = new MySecondFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            bundle.putInt("CurrentPosition", getAdapterPosition());
            bundle.putIntArray("x", kolamTracingGameList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getX());
            bundle.putIntArray("y", kolamTracingGameList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getY());
            bundle.putInt("Level", (getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            bundle.putString("GameType", "Kolam");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Problem is when I close `Fragment` **F2** and `Fragment` **F1** comes to foreground. Whole **F1** is recreating(`onViewCreated()` is called again). I don't want **F1** to get recreated again when it comes to foreground.

Comment: We'll, it's just the way it works. If you have some code that's running in `onViewCreated`, try moving it.

Comment: You are wrong. `onViewCreated()` does not mean the fragment is being recreated. It just means that the view of the fragment is being recreated. If you want to run code when fragment is created, then put it into `onCreated()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second fragment use add instead of replace.

`replace`- removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment.when the back button is pressed in fragment F2,fragment in oncreateView is called again.

`add` -retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused'.when the back button is pressed in fragment F2,none of the methods of the fragment F1  are called again.

```
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, f2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the Fragment to keep it's state and don't go through `onCreateView` you can not replace it. Let's take a look at Fragment's life cycle:

When you call replace on a fragment you are basically telling the container to remove all present fragments, and add a new one. If you remove a fragment, `onPause()` will be called all the way until `onViewDestroyed()`, that meaning that if you get the fragment instance back and add it to the container, it has no View, so `onCreateView()` will be called.

If you call add on Fragment2, it will be the Visible Fragment but Fragment1 will still be in the container. Now once you remove Fragment2(backPress or programmatically), Fragment1 will become visible without calling `onCreateView()`, or any other state.

Code:

Replace this:

```
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

With:

```
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, f2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time before doing the `FragmentTransaction` you are creating a new `Fragment`, either `F1` or `F2`. You have couple of options:

1. Keep a global reference to `F1/F2` as they are created. So you only create a new one if they are `null`.
2. Or, if you don't want to keep global reference, assign a unique tag to the `F1/F2`. That way you can call `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` which will return you the `Fragment` if it still exists. Then you do your transaction.

Example for option 2:

```
FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyFragment f1 = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f1_fragment");

if (f1 != null) f1 = new MyFragment();

FragmentTransaction gameTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       gameTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
gameTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, f1, "f1_fragment")
    .commit();
```

Comment: Can you provide one example with some code for 2nd option. @Ahmadulhoq

Comment: @Hiren I've added the example, please check the edit.