# avoid fragment recreation BottomNavigationView

Tags: android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller, bottomnavigationview, fragmentmanager

i want to avoid fragment recreation by using BottomNavigationView
i read about that FragmentTransaction.replace is the problem and changing to add would help, but that didn't work for me..

maybe you can see here where i'm wrong

this is my Host Activity which hosting 3 fragments with BottomNavigationView

'''

```
class Host : AppCompatActivity() {




var fragment: Fragment? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_host)

    //for hide the actionBar (contains Fragment name) on top of the screen
    val actionBar = supportActionBar
    actionBar?.hide()


    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val navView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    navView?.setupWithNavController(navController)


    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

    fragmentStayAlive()

  

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}




fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }

private fun fragmentStayAlive(){

    val fragment1: Fragment = LobbyFragment()
    val fragment2: Fragment = GameSessionFragment()
    val fragment3: Fragment = UserStatusFragment()
    val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    var active = fragment1

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment3, "UserStatusFragment").hide(
        fragment3
    ).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2, "GameSessionFragment").hide(
        fragment2
    ).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1, "LobbyFragment").commit();

    val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        object : BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                when (item.getItemId()) {
                    R.id.lobbyFragment -> {
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit()
                        active = fragment1

                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.gameSessionFragment -> {
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit()
                        active = fragment2


                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.userStatusFragment -> {
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit()
                        active = fragment3


                        return true
                    }
                }

                replaceFragment(active, null, true, true)
                return false


            }
        }
}

fun replaceFragment(
    fragment: Fragment,
    @Nullable bundle: Bundle?,
    popBackStack: Boolean,
    findInStack: Boolean
) {
    val fm = supportFragmentManager
    val ft: FragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction()
    val tag = fragment.javaClass.name

    val parentFragment: Fragment?
    parentFragment = if (findInStack && fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) {
        fm.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    } else {
        fragment
    }
    // if user passes the @bundle in not null, then can be added to the fragment
    if (bundle != null) {
        parentFragment!!.arguments = bundle
    } else {
        parentFragment!!.arguments = null
    }
    // this is for the very first fragment not to be added into the back stack.
    if (popBackStack) {
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    } else {
        ft.addToBackStack(parentFragment.javaClass.name + "")
    }
    ft.add(R.id.nav_view, parentFragment, tag)
    ft.commit()
    fm.executePendingTransactions()
}
```

'''

thanks for all the helpers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031208/how-to-avoid-fragment-recreation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130713/bottomnavigationview-how-to-avoid-recreation-of-fragments-and-reuse-them/50939140